# Brackets in Bracket in Java

Tags: java

What actually means using brackets in brackets while initializing e.g. new List ?

```
new ArrayList<String>() 
{
    {
       add("A");
    }
};
```

Does it mean that after creating new reference method is invoking ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a clever idiom for creating and initializing a collection.

What is actually happening is that you are creating an instance of an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList` which has an instance initializer block that calls `add` on list instance to populate it.  The inner `{...}` is the instance initializer block.

A similar trick can be used to create pre-initialized maps.